# Трассировка запросов из asp.net core в postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, asp.net, core

мне необходимо посмотреть все запросы которые были отправленны моим core приложением в postgreSQL. Подскажите по средствам чего я это могу сделать?

Comment: Если используете Entity Framework, то можете включить [логирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/) в нём.

Comment: Посмотрите [Database Profiling with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/database-profiling-with-visual-studio/)

Comment: В самом Постгресе есть [Error Reporting and Logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-logging.html)